# How to pass an object array to webAPI List

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic HTML which is calling a WebAPI function using jquery ajax call. HTML sends an array of objects which should get mapped to the functions parameter that i am receiving as LIST. If i remove array and send only 1 object and also remove list from function, then my code works and object is passed successfully to the parameter.

JavaScript code is as below

```
    function Call_Service () {
var input =
{
    STATUS: "MY New Status",
    CATEGORY: "My Value"
};

var input2 =
{
    STATUS: "MY New Status2",
    CATEGORY: "My Value2"
};

var input_array = new Array();
input_array[0] = input;
input_array[1] = input2;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:34989/api/TMSPortal/objectPOC",
    data: input_array,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

C# WebAPI is as below

```
        public Int64 objectPOC(List<TMS_STATUS> _Status)
    {

        Int64 retValu = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _Status.Count; i++)
        {
            retValu++;
        }

        return retValu;
    }
```

Comment: Try changing objectPOC method parameter to TMS_STATUS[] instead of a List.

Comment: @KevinJunghans that didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i came to know that Web-API currently don't allow more than 1 complex parameter therefore i had make my work done by following workaround. Let me know if someone has better solution:

Changed the Web-API function to receive JObject and then extracted my Complex objects from it. Web-API functions looks as below:

```
        public Int64 objectPOC(JObject jsonWrapper)
    {

        dynamic jsonValues = jsonWrapper;
        JArray jsonInput = jsonValues.input;
        JArray jsonInput2 = jsonValues.input2;

        List<TMS_STATUS> _Status = jsonInput.ToObject<List<TMS_STATUS>>();
        List<TMS_STATUS> _Status2 = jsonInput2.ToObject<List<TMS_STATUS>>();


        Int64 retValu = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _Status.Count; i++)
        {
            retValu++;
        }

        return retValu;
    }
```

Ajax Call is as follows:

```
    function Call_Service () {
var input =
{
    STATUS: "MY New Status",
    CATEGORY: "My Value"
};

var input2 =
{
    STATUS: "MY New Status2",
    CATEGORY: "My Value2"
};

var input_array = new Array();
input_array[0] = input;
input_array[1] = input2;

alert(input_array[0].STATUS);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:34989/api/TMSPortal/objectPOC",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        input: input_array,
        input2: input_array
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple complex type parameters, create a model and expose them as properties inside the model. In Web API you can have only 1 complex type input parameter out of the box.