# JSON array is converting to a generic list, but not converting to a generic collection. Why?

Tags: json, list, collections, asp.net-web-api

I am sending a Json Array from the client web application to asp.net webapi. 
For example,

```
{
    "SurveyId":3423,
    "CreatorId":4235,
    "GlobalAppId":34,
    "AssociateList":[
        {"AssociateId":4234},
        {"AssociateId":43},
        {"AssociateId":23423},
        {"AssociateId":432}
    ],
    "IsModelDirty":false,
    "SaveMode":null
}
```

Here Associate List is a JSON Array,
Usually it will automatically serialize to a List<> object.

Using the below code ,i am posting the response to the WebApi

```
public IEnumerable<Associate> Post(ResponseStatus responseStatus)
{
   return this.responsestatusrepository.ResponseStatusCheck(responseStatus);               
}
```

The ResponseStatus class is shown below.

```
public class ResponseStatus : AppBaseModel
{
        public int SurveyId { get; set; }
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        public int GlobalAppId { get; set; }
        public List<Associate> AssociateList { get; set; }
}
```

I have changed the List<> to Collection<> as a part of my code analysis correction. 
ie, `public Collection<Associate> AssociateList { get; set; }`

But it is always getting a null value when we are using collection instead of List. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Try to use IEnumerable<Associate> or check this also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071120/how-to-pass-an-object-array-to-webapi-list) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I will have to answer this in an indirect way.
What you are passing on to the server is an array of objects (in JSON format), but once you start processing this in C# the array of objects is now treated as a single c# object. Inside this object, your model expects one of the fields to be a Collection of Associate.

Right, when I work with JSON data similar to whats mentioned in this case - I prefer to use Newtonsofts' JOject.

So here is how I made the C# object with the JSON data you provided:

Used your model:

```
public class ResponseStatus
{
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public int GlobalAppId { get; set; }
    public Collection<Associate> AssociateList { get; set; }
}

public class Associate
{
    public int AssociateId { get; set; }
}
```

Made a routine which takes string (the JSON data), and returns an object of type ResponseStatus:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

---------------------------------------------------------------------

public static ResponseStatus GetResponseStatusObject(string jsonData)
{
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    return jObject.ToObject<ResponseStatus>();
}
```

Now when I call this method and pass on the exact same JSON data which you provided, I get this:

[image: Breakpoint after method ran]

This might not directly solve your problem, but hopefully guide you in the right direction in understanding array/object serialization when working with JavaScript/C#.

Best of luck!